# Ajuda PIVOT - SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, select, pivot

Tenho uma tabela com os dados:

```
unidade  tipo  valor  
      1     2  10,00  
      1     3  15,00  
      2     2  16,00  
      3     3  10,00  
      3     1  25,00
```

Preciso fazer um select com pivot que me traga

```
unidade tipo1 tipo2 tipo3
1        0,00 10,00 15,00
2        0,00 16,00  0,00  
3       25,00  0,00  0.00
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: seria interessante você posta a estrutura da tabela e o que você já tentou fazer, clique no [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/153228/edit) e modifique sua pergunta deixando mais clara.

Comment: Pedro, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Conforme sugestão do GOKU você poderia editar sua pergunta incluindo o DDL da tabela. Inclua também o banco de dados que você está usando na pergunta (alguns bancos possuem melhor suporte do que outros, sua resposta pode variar conforme o SGBD).